# Check if a HTML string contains a block element

Tags: php, html

I need to wrap HTML with a `span` element or a `div` element if necessary. As HTML block elements cannot be nested into a inline element:

```
<span><div /></span>
```

I need a function that checks if a variable `$html` contains at least 1 block element.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for now,
the real list of tag names that are on block-level [is quite long](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) ...

```
function check_if_html_contains_block_elements($html) {
    if (!$html) {
        return false;
    }
    
    // There are more. But these tag names are most common
    $blocklevelElements = [
        'div',
        'p',
        'blockquote',
        'figure',
        'form',
        'h1',
        'h2',
        'h3',
        'h4',
        'h5',
        'h6',
        'ul',
        'ol',
        'pre',
        'table',
    ];
    
    foreach ($blocklevelElements as $element) {
        if (stripos($html, '<' . $element) !== false) {
            if (preg_match('#<' . $element . '[\s/>]#i', $html)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here are some test cases:

```
$testCases = [
    [ /* expected result */ false, /* $html */ '' ],
    [ false, '<span>bla</span>'],
    [ false, 'asdf<span />bla'],
    [ true,  '<P>Hallo</P>'],
    [ true,  '<p >Hallo</p >'],
    [ true,  '<div class="hu">hu</div>'],
    [ true,  '<ol><li>hu</li></ol>'],
    [ true,  '<div />'],
    [ true,  '<div/>'],
    [ false, '<pp/>'],
    [ false, '<pp />'],
    [ false, '<pp class=""></pp>'],
    [ false, '<pp></pp>'],
];
```